# How to make responsive css hexagon grid in a snake shape when on a small screen?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid, responsive

Right now the hexagons look like this: [5 hexagon grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztylO.png)

I want them to look like this when viewed on a small screen: [vertical hexagon grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmTiW.png)

```css
.hexagon-gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.hexagon-gallery::before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  padding-bottom: 55%;
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
}

.hex {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  grid-row-end: span 4;
  display: flex;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgb(5, 132, 67);
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon-gallery">
  <div
    class="hex bg-center row-start-1 col-start-1">
  </div>
  <div
    class="hex bg-center row-start-1 col-start-3">
  </div>
  <div
    class="hex bg-center row-start-1 col-start-5">
  </div>
  <div
    class="hex bg-center row-start-4 col-start-2 ">
  </div>
  <div
    class="hex bg-center row-start-4 col-start-4 ">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello, your code actually only shows stacking hexagons.  Are you looking for something like this : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wvJgbba ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Yes and no. I want them to fit together like that, but only 5 of them in a single line. I'm really confused about how to make the 'nth child' work. How are you getting them to repeat?

Comment: i use a repeatted svg background with shape-outside  within a pseudo-element to make them wrap around. for nth-child() and grid , you 'll need to make them span 2 columns and then decide where they stand col 1 or 2.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Ah ok... I still feel like I'm missing something on your code. I've figured out the columns, but am struggling with the rows for some reason. I need like 15 of them

Comment: i added  below a snippet for example. a negative margin could be enough

Comment: read this: https://css-tricks.com/hexagons-and-beyond-flexible-responsive-grid-patterns-sans-media-queries/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thank you for the snippet! It works in codepen, but not js fiddle. And it kind of works in my angular project. It's a great starting point, thank you!!

Comment: ?? looks okay in jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/os18jhk0/1/ Ireduced width to see them better. Do you have a sandbox or so online to demonstrate ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Okay this is weird, now it works. Maybe it was a temporary glitch. No I don't, it's part of a larger web design project. And for some reason js fiddle and codepen won't run my code, I think because of the tailwind.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of the idea commented earlier.

notice i moved the pseudo to the hex themselves , so the grid expands from children it holds , no need to set a row height, children do it themselves.

```css
.hexagon-gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:  1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap:1em;
}

.hex::before {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;;
  padding-bottom: 120%;
}

.hex {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  margin-bottom:-30% ;
  display: flex;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
  background-color: rgb(5, 132, 67);  
}
.hex:nth-child(odd){
  grid-column: 2 / span 2
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon-gallery">
  <div
    class="hex bg-center row-start-1 col-start-1">
  </div>
  <div
    class="hex bg-center row-start-1 col-start-3">
  </div>
  <div
    class="hex bg-center row-start-1 col-start-5">
  </div>
  <div
    class="hex bg-center row-start-4 col-start-2 ">
  </div>
  <div
    class="hex bg-center row-start-4 col-start-4 ">
  </div>
</div>
```